# Xcode Webview Output "null"

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I'm developing an iPad app that supposed to output a website to another view, but when the second view loads, it comes up null. I'm using storyboard to link a button to push the web view controller and load the webpage into that view. The code works fine in the first view (indicated by NSLog), but NSURL never makes it to the second view (NSLog "Null").

Code in IBAction on first view:

```
self.sanctuaryWebViewController = [[SanctuaryWebViewController alloc]init];
self.sanctuaryWebViewController.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.org"];
```

Code in ViewDidLoad Second View Controller:

```
NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[webView loadRequest:requestObject];
```

I have done this in an Iphone app fine declaring a nav delegate to push the view, but not sure if using storyboard or splitview  has anything to do with the problem. I spent hours searching for help and tried several different ways to code, but no go. I think I'm close, but not quite there. Using Xcode 4.4 and running on OS 10.8; IOS 5.1

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was declaring UIWebview twice. "webview" and "_webview". I removed the instant variable declared in .h and kept the property. Made sure "_webview" was used. Also, Since I linked a segue to a button, I got rid of the IBAction method and replaced it with the prepareForSegue method, which calls the segue. Really had know idea what I was doing using storyboard. I knew about the segue methods, but did not realize they are not linked to the button like IBAction methods. They seem to be used in similar way as calling xib files, but calling segues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us more of the second view controller's code?  I'm assuming you are using ARC?  I assume you mean the result is coming up nil rather than NSNull (there is a difference)?  Have you connected the webView in the second view controller to the UIWebView in the Storyboard/IB?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm using ARC. I suspect you are expecting more code. My iPhone app only has the code above in the viewDidLoad method of the second view controller and works as expected. I have no reason to assume it would not work in the ipad version of the app. The other code in the method is for the activity indicator and NSLog. I assume null because that is how NSLog displays it. The webview is connected to the property for UIWevbView via Storyboard/IB. I should also add that the push works, but the webview does not load the webpage.